# Deleting previous iCloud iphone backups and only keeping the last one?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, storage

I reached the 5gb limit of my storage, and when I go into my iCloud settings in my iphone, I see the following:

[image]

Would I lose any data if I delete the previous backup of 3.62gb and create a new backup that will take only 1.45gb?

Or is the 1.45gb an incremental backup that builds on top of the 3.62gb?

Comment: I've been backing up my iPhones to that 5GB for over a decade & if left to itself it just deals with it. I wouldn't worry about it unless it complains.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's complaining that storage is full, that's why I was wondering if this can be done.

Comment: I can't find that specific page. In Apple ID/Manage Storage/Backups I can see each of my devices & how much space each takes, with a delete option… but I don't see that info.